# Spring webflux: how to use custom jackson ObjectWriter in ResponseEntityResultHandler?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, spring-webflux

I need to use custom objectWriter depend on some conditions for writing JSON reponse in webflux application.

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> handleResult(ServerWebExchange exchange, HandlerResult result) {
    /*Few writers can be use there depend on some condtions*/
    ObjectWriter writer = ObjectWriterProvider.getObjectWriter(/**/);
    /*set writer */
    return super.handleResult(exchange, result);        
}
```

There were

```
ObjectWriterInjector.set(new Modifier(objectWriter, prettyPrint));
```

JAX-RS

I there any way to use custom object writer in webflux without overriding full `super.handleResult` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this bean in your configuration class. You can customize ObjectMapper.

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder configureObjectMapper() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    //objectMapper.writer(Yourwritter);
    builder.configure(objectMapper);
    return builder;
}
```